# Conditionally have anchor links send user to a different page, rather than load to ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have a view that contains an anchor link.  That link has an href to another url in my site.  Angular tries to load that site, using html5mode.  I would rather just have default behavior for that link and send the user off to the url.  How can I specify that this particular link should behave like a normal html link, not an angular route?

Comment: Could you post more specifics?  The URL that Angular is sending vs. the URL that you want?

Comment: If you need the link to lead to another page, then you probably shouldn't be using an anchor link. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AngularJS understands a few rules that will make the browser perform a full reload. The rules are documented under the 'Html link rewriting' section in the [$location service documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes_html5-mode_html-link-rewriting).

From the documentation:

In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.

- Links that contain target element
  Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
- Absolute links that go to a different domain
  Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
- Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined
  Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

Note that the last example only works if you have used the `base` element in the head section of your page:

```
<base href="/my-base/" />
```