# Telling Angular Js to ignore a specific route

Tags: angularjs

I have set up my routing in Angular and all works fine:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider.
      when('/', { templateUrl: '/Home/Index' }).
      when('/User', { templateUrl: '/User/Index' });
```

However I now have an anchor tag to work as a logout button which will just redirect the user to /User/Logout, and logout will then log the user out and redirect them to the login page. So what I want is for angular js to just ignore this specific route and allow it to do a normal http redirect. This seems like something that should be really easy but I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem.

I know I could do a click event and do a window.location change in the click event but that seems like a really hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

specify `target="_self"` in your anchors, so that angularjs does not rewrite URLs. See the discussion here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location)

Comment: This is necessary for me in the Dropdown of Bootstrap!

Comment: This helped me get the Register and Login links working in the MVC 6 template, where the rest of my app is Angular.

Comment: Extremely useful when dealing with login/logout sequences using mix of express and angular routes.

Comment: so simple! Never knew this was possible! Can confirm this is working using a Python Flask web application, in which the "application" page has all the Angular code where it's routing takes over the python app. Very useful

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with redirectTo also:

```
 .when('/User/Logout', {
            redirectTo: function(obj,path,search) {
                window.location.href=path;
            }
        })
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer to that question!