# Request url when html5Mode(true)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have enabled `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`.

However I have django as backend. On `/logout/` I need to ask the url directly to the server as if `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)` or simply visiting: `example.com/logout/` and not in the fron-end.

Which angular command should I use to "force" ask the `/logout/` url from the server?

Comment: One way is to just use window.location = "example.com/logout/" which by-passes AngularJS

Comment: @LostInComputer can you create me an example with an optimal handler as well (I guess either by `$watch`-ing the `$location` or `$routeProvider`)? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to set the url directly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @davekr I have in `urls.py` `url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),`. The view is: `def logout(request): auth_logout(request);return HttpResponseRedirect('/');`. So I need a way to auth logout the user with that view (I am using [python social auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) if it matters).

Comment: @Diolor So why not to return json with a redirect url from the view and then use it on frontend and change the $location to the url?

Comment: @davekr example please?

Comment: In view: `return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"redirect":"/"}), mimetype='application/javascript')` In JS: `$http.get("logout/").success(function(data) {$location.path(data.redirect)})`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Turns out that are are two possible solutions:

1) See
[Telling Angular Js to ignore a specific route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407024/telling-angular-js-to-ignore-a-specific-route)

2) Or use $window.location.

Here is an example:

```
$scope.onLogoutClicked = function() {
    $window.location = "http://google.com";
}
```

Difference between $window.location and $location

> **When should I use $location?**
>
> Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.
>
> **What does it not do?**
>   It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

Notes:

- $window is a wrapper for window so that it can be unit tested.
- $window.location = "URL" and $window.location.href = "URL" does the
  same thing