# AngularJS Routing in a Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angularjs

I am currently building a Wordpress site which has a few interactive bits using AngularJS. Everything works fine, however, when I go to a page which corresponds to my Angular routing setup, the rest of the links on the site then fail to work.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-view">
<ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

... my view is as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="LinksCtrl" ng-init="init()">
... rest of view ...
</div>
```

... any my routing is set up as follows:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider.when('/links/', {
    templateUrl: APP_SETTINGS.baseUrl + '/assets/js/views/links.html',
    controller: 'LinksCtrl'
});
```

So, when I navigate around the site, all works OK, but when I then go to /links/, the page (and all Angular app related stuff works and loads), but the rest of the links in the site then fail to load.

So firstly, I am not sure I have to have the controller defined in both the view and routes, and secondly, surely the page should just init without routing? If I disable routing, non of the Angular view displays.

I guess my question should be as to whether or not this is actually possible.

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Most likely, your links that fail are **relative** links as opposed to **absolute**. ```some/page.html``` will be relative, meaning it'll take your current path, *APP_SETTINGS.baseUrl/links/some/page.html*. Absolute path ```/some/page.html``` will always start from base, giving you *APP_SETTINGS.baseUrl/some/page.html*. Try changing links that don't work to absolute (add a forward slash to beginning, if this is the case.

Comment: You don't need `class="ng-view"`.  You are calling the LinksCtrl via the attribute and the routing; I think you can delete `ng-controller="LinksCtrl"`

Comment: Thanks guys. @Simon H, removing ng-controller="LinksCtrl" still makes no difference.I have removed any ways.

cbayram, thanks, but I am using Wordpress so links are absolute by default. Nothing to change there unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found here has worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17407179/102086.

Basically, you just need to add a target of "_self". Top the links you want ignored.