# How to ignore specific links from routing?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 1.3.14 with Angular Route.
Now, I have some specific links like this one:

```
<a target="_self" ng-href="#next" role="menuitem">Next</a>
```

And on this link there is a jQuery plugin attached, that opens/closes the accordion. Now currently, it just takes AngularJS routing into effect and redirects me to /#next. How can I disable that ?

I have tried setting target="_self", but no luck.

Comment: hope this link helps   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407024/telling-angular-js-to-ignore-a-specific-route

Comment: I already have target="_self" on the link.

Comment: I need it to have href="#next", for jQuery plugin to know what to do.