# AngularJS routing and anchor hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are creating an Angular App from past one year or so and till now we never used routing. Now that we have tried it in some of our pages we love the dynamic loading of templates and the response time.

The only problem we have is that many pages have links like`<a href="#selectedTab">`. At some places the anchor element just signifies which tab is currently selected and in other it actually navigates to certain content.

After we added the routing code like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', {
        templateUrl: '/ctx/page1.jsp',
        controller: 'page1Controller'
    }).when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: 'page2',
        controller: 'page2Controller'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/' //what can I write here for normal # behavior
    });
});
```

All our normal navigation anchors naturally do not work. Is there a way to write some code in the `otherwise` clause to ignore some of the anchors?.
I have already read [How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs) but it assumes users are creating a new app and has a work around. Also `target="_self"` attribute solves it but I will have to check all my `<a>` tags to remove '#' which will be at least in 4 digits.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Do you have a base href in your html?

e.g.

`<base href="/" />`

can you try it with

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

---

add target="_self" to your anchor links,. This prevents AngularJS from rewriting the URL. See [This answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407024/telling-angular-js-to-ignore-a-specific-route) and [this discussion](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the last paragraph. My app has hundreds of such links, in total it may have thousands of `a` tags and seems like a mammoth task to go through each on of those.

Comment: Must have read over that. Can you try the suggestions from the updated answer

Comment: I tried `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` but then when I have a normal anchor like `<a href="#tab1">..</a>` then clicking on it shows `http://.../page1.jsp#!#tab1` in the address bar. Still breaks my older changes... But this is a good clue, I will look into it once again

Comment: With a quick test it also seems that when I use base href my normal anchors like `<a href="/myapp/somepage.jsp">..</a>` gets captured by routing