# Meteor, Angular routes, Nginx and SSL - how to route /path to another server with rewrite

Tags: angularjs, ssl, nginx, path, dns

I have:

- DigitalOcean VPS
- Meteor application with routing in Angular
- Nginx as a reverse-proxy
- SSL for my domain, configured with Nginx (also redirecting http to https)
- another hosting (!) with Wordpress blog there
- something doma.in with DNS set to DigitalOcean VPS and Meteor app is there

How can I "rewrite" doma.in/blog to the blog, but with this same URL? (without redirect).

Comment: Not really sure what you're attempting to do here. You have an angular app running on doma.in/ (in the index.html) file, and a blog on doma.in/blog, and you want links from the angular app that land on doma.in/blog to land in the wordpress page instead of a subroute in angular? Or do you just want people landing on doma.in/blog to see the wordpress blog, despite the wordpress blog having a different url?

Answer (score 2):

Try this nginx configuration:

```
location  ^/blog {
  rewrite /blog(.*) $1  break; #cut the /blog path
  proxy_pass         http://blog.com:8000; #then pass it to the blog domain/port
  proxy_redirect     off;  #without redirecting 
  proxy_buffering off;    #or buffering
}
```

As for angular, it simply needs to avoid/skip the route, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407024/telling-angular-js-to-ignore-a-specific-route) on SO