# External Links in Angular App

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm in the process of incorporating Angular into a single page of an existing rails app.

Everything is working perfectly with the routing within the page using the following

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/services/:id', {
        templateUrl: "/javascripts/angular/templates/service_ui/service.html",
        controller: "ServiceCtrl"
     })

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

However, I'd like to maintain normal functionality for links that are not related to Angular. For example, we have a number of links in the header that link elsewhere that are now being caught by the angular router.

I've found some potential solutions at: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/basidvjscRk

But the base path method doesnt seem to work..and the target="_self" method is rather obtrusive. Is there a better way to let angular ignore routes that aren't specified in the config function?

I know there is an .otherwise() method but again this seems like a hack. Am I missing something?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think the Google Groups answer is pretty solid.  The `target="_self"` method seems to definitely be in the spirit of Angular since it's a declarative approach to the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023338/conditionally-have-anchor-links-send-user-to-a-different-page-rather-than-load/13031727

Comment: target="_self" seems to cause a full page reload when using Angular in conjunction with turbolinks (for same-site pages).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs Normal Links with html5Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a relatively "traditional" web application in that most of the links trigger full page reloads; very few links go through Angular's routing system. Right after our module definition, we have the following:

```
app.run(function($location, $rootElement) {
  $rootElement.off('click');
});
```

This stops the [built-in interception of clicks](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b8ea7f6aba2e675b85826b0bee1f21ddd7b866a5/src/ng/location.js#L513-540) that Angular uses to manipulate the URL and such when you click on a link; the catch is that you now have to use `$location` manually whenever you want Angular *to* do its URL magic (e.g. via an `ngClick` and a function that manipulates `$location` accordingly).

You may consider using `$rootElement.off` combined with a special directive or configuration function that re-installs this behavior on links that you detect contain a certain URL fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that may work for you is to change the `$rootElement`: the link interception only occurs within the element that is declared as the ng-app.

In my case, I switched from `<body ng-app="myApp">` to `<section id="my-rich-area" ng-app="myApp">`.

This worked for me as I didn't have any same-domain, non-angular links within that section, ymmv.