# Angular add unwanted anchors to my urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hashtag

When I do a link to a simple webpage (not in $routeProvider)
The page is loading and then Angular adds a anchor to the end of the url.

```
Example: www.test.com/home
* page loading *
Then: www.test.com/home#home
```

How do I prevent this?

I am using AngularJS v1.1.5 (not stable yet)

Comment: Please don't confuse hashtags (which are a way of flagging a word to be linked as a search term on Twitter and other social networks) with fragment identifiers in URLs.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using v1.1.5, I've seen this too. If you switch to stable 1.0.7 it doesn't happen, at the sacrifice of some features.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I really need those new features so... I will continue using this one and waiting for it to be stable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have links that are not related to your angular app, so angular should not append anything to them?
This is because the `a` tag is a directive in angular. If you want to skip it, you can add `target="_self"`
See [Angularjs Normal Links with html5Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode/16838013#16838013)

Comment: Ok thank you Eduard, yes this is my problem. So i have to add target="_self" on all my links? No workaround this?