# Angularjs Html5 mode links doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs in some parts of the page and I need html5 mode for reading the parameters from url. The problem is that whenever I turn on html5 mode the simple static links doesn't work, the url is being changed in navigation bar however it doesn't change the page ? Is there a way to make simple html links work in html5 mode ?

Comment: Someone can mark it as duplicate. Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Apache (or nginx, or node, or whatever server you are using) to always return an index.html page when accessing your domain. That way, the HTML5 mode in angular will work also as a regular page link