# AngularJS HTML5 Routing Enabled : Passing URL Back to server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, html, angularjs-routing

I have an AngularJS SPA with Html5Mode enabled. I removed the hashes from my URLS and everything works great except for one issue. Our site has download links for downloading documents from the server via a HTTPGET call to a MVC controller method. Angular no longer passes the route back to the server because it thinks it needs to handle it. How do I tell Angular's routing engine to pass the GET back to the server? I have considered switching the download to a WebAPI, but I read mixed results with this approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Go figure I post for help and figure it out! :) The solution is to add target='_self' to your anchor tag. Any of the other target values work too; "_blank", "_top" and so on. I tested this in IE 9, 10; Chrome 40-43, Opera 25-29, and Safari 5.1.

Comment: It's better to post an answer and mark the answer as the solution rather than a comment

Comment: Sorry first time doing this. Done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs Normal Links with html5Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! :) The solution is to add target='_self' to your anchor tag. Any of the other target values work too; "_blank", "_top" and so on. I tested this in IE 9, 10; Chrome 40-43, Opera 25-29, and Safari 5.1

Comment: That sounds like it should probably has a much better solution. :)