# AngularJS - How to stop <base> tag + html5Mode + $location from preventing anchor tag links to refresh the webpage

Tags: angularjs

This is my JS (I set html5Mode to True and I am using `$http $window` and `$location`:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // Important. Needed for URLs.
}])

.controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "$location", function($http, $window, $location) {
```

The base tag is also set, like so:

```
<base href="/">
```

This is my html page:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="/">Home &#x25BC;</a></li>
        <li><a href='/post'>Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="ctrl.logoutUser()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The issue is, when I click any of the links, the URL updates but the page does not refresh. If I remove `$location` from my controller then it works properly, but I need `$location` to grab the URL from my JS for other purposes. Is there a way for me to stop AngularJS from preventing to refresh the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add `target='_self'` to the anchor tags, like so:

```
<li><a href="/" target='_self'>Home &#x25BC;</a></li>
```

The answer was taken from this SO post: [Angularjs Normal Links with html5Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode)

Answer (score 0):

For those using ui-router, always try to use

```
ui-sref="stateName.childState"
```

instead of href="myurl", this will prevent reloading issue.

reference:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#ui-sref