# How to deal with AngularJS formatting forward slash in my URL to escape code %2F

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, escaping

I am trying to implement a single page application with *AngularJS 1.6.0-rc.2*, and it keeps formatting a forward slash to its escape code **%2F** in my URL. Because of that it gets not detected by the route.

I have read about hashbangs and tried fixing it by setting the HTML5 mode on, but the url keeps getting converted.

**Questions**

1 - Why Angular has to do such a thing, what's the purpose of making this conversion?

2 - I noticed version 1.3 doesn't do that. Should I be using this version instead?

3 - How to fix it?

**More Details**

I have 3 pages and 1 javascript file

- *index.htm*
- *home.htm*
- *forecast.htm*
- *app.js*

Here's some part of *app.js* that I believe might be relevant:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.htm',
        controller: 'homeController'

    })
    .when('/forecast', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/forecast.htm',
        controller: 'forecastController'

    })
```

My *index.htm* has my **ng-view**

And part of *home.htm*:

```
 <a href="#/forecast" class="btn btn-primary">Get Forecast</a>
```

So when the link *'Get Forecast'* is clicked, the URL I get is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:65381/index.htm#!/#%2Fforecast
```

That means, that URL doesn't match the route then I still have my *home.htm* content instead of *forecast.htm*

Comment: Try removing the #, otherwise add a * to your routeProvider when to enable html5Mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode this question should help you

Comment: @SterlingArcher, removing **#** I get this _URL_: `http://127.0.0.1:65381/forecast`. If I just enable HTML5 my _home.htm_ content don't get displayed. I tried the adding the attribute _target=self_ in my link but nothing changed. Reading the $location documentation I also tried: `html5Mode({
            enabled: false,
            requireBase: false,
            rewriteLinks: false
        });` but it still adds the escape code to the url

Answer (score 2):

I got some help from a friend and the solution is to add **'!'** on my link, so instead of:

```
<a href="#/forecast" class="btn btn-primary">Get Forecast</a>
```

it should be this:

```
<a href="#!/forecast" class="btn btn-primary">Get Forecast</a>
```

I know this is the hashbang mode, and it's deprecated, I just wanted to know how to play around with it properly, with Angular.

Ref:
[What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

So I will update my links now...