# can't navigate away from angular page in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use Angular and ui router in my rails app and I think I'm almost there. It all works and angular displays my partial in the correct place but I can't seem to navigate away from the angular page. When I click a link the links address appears correctly in the navigation bar but the browser doesn't navigate to the new page and I see no activity in my rails console. However if I then click reload on my browsers address bar the correct page loads. I have turbolinks disabled.

my HTML

```
%h1 Angular Page
%a{"href" => "/"} non angular home page
%br
.angular-view(ui-view)
%script#template{"type"=>"text/ng-template"}=render 'template'
```

my Angular routing

```
@myApp.config ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/clubs/:Club_id/training",
      templateUrl: "template"
     })
```

I wanted to use ui router to handle all the different 'routes' within the angular page but I wanted to leave the rest of my routing to rails for now. Is this possible?

I found the solution thanks to Sergeys' comment below. The answer is that angular intercepts clicks in order to manipulate the URL. I inserted

```
myApp.run(($location, $rootElement) ->
  $rootElement.off('click')
)
```

as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755240/external-links-in-angular-app) which fixed it for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755240/external-links-in-angular-app

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. Missed that question when I was looking. $rootElement.off('click') makes it work.

Comment: Fyi, it was found by 'angular link to external' search in google.

Comment: I recommend you update your question with solution and link to source.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode