# Mixing Angular routing with MVC Partial Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, routes

I would like to use angular templates for most of my application, but for some pages I'd want to use aspnet mvc controllers and partial views displayed in the ng-view.

I've been trying things like this with the routing:

```
when('/AccountX/Manage', { templateUrl: '/Account/Manage', controller: AccountController }).
when('/Account/Manage', { controller: AccountController }).
```

I've also changed the Account/Manage forms to be ajax, but it seems after posting a form, angular proceeds with a get.

I'm using html5Mode without hashbangs. My aim is to have always normal urls.

Is there a way to tell angular to avoid some routes? Like IgnoreRoute in aspnet MVC?

Sorry if I'm too vague. For my own understanding, I just want to find a working concept of mixing standard aspnet mvc with angular regardless if it's considered good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are ways to use the $location service to accomplish what you are requesting:

[Conditionally have anchor links send user to a different page, rather than load to ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023338/conditionally-have-anchor-links-send-user-to-a-different-page-rather-than-load)

Comment: The target attribute doesn't help for managing problems with form posts. It does work fine for the arbitrary link thou.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a big part of making it work is to **avoid assigning ng-app to the html element**. When the ng-app is smaller, the parts outside it will not be affected by the routing.

There are some potential issues along the way:

- `ng-app` can't be nested.
- only the first `ng-app` becomes automatically bootstrapped.
- latter `ng-app` is instead added like this: `angular.bootstrap(element[, modules]);`

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap

When there are links within the ng-app that should not trigger the angular routing, it's avoided by adding `target="_self"` (or any target attribute).

There is a good project template for mvc4+angular+breeze available which can be studied and tested. (At least VS 2012 Update 2 is required for it.)
http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template

### Conclusion

By partitioning the application within the html page such that there are parts that isn't affected by the routing, and excluding individual links within an ng-app when needed, Asp.NET MVC functionality can successfully be mixed with AngularJS.