# passport js not being redirected until refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

when I visit */auth/provider/* through an anchor link a blank page opens but *passport.authenticate('provider'))* is not called, if I visit */auth/provider/* directly *passport.authenticate('provider'))* is called.

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var routes = require('./routes');
var app = module.exports = express();


passport.use('provider', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://example.com/oauth/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://example.com/oauth/token',
    clientID: "777myclientid",
    clientSecret: "555dontstealmyclientsecret",
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/callback'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
  }
));

app.configure(function(){

  app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile)

  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

app.get('/auth/provider', passport.authenticate('provider'));
```

Comment: Are you using a client-side framework like Angular that might be 'catching' those routes? If so, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13031727/893780).

Comment: I was using angular and that answer solved it thanks