# Serving a file download in a AngularJS html5mode express environment

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm trying to serve a pdf file download on a app essentially generated with the angular-fullstack yeoman generator.

In app.js html5mode is set to true.

I tried building a download link using an  tag and href but just nothing happens. Watching network activity reveals, that it's not generating an get request.

Server backend is an express server serving partials and other stuff.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I also tried to set up a route with

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the file download link on the subdomain like *file.domain.com*?

[This example](https://github.com/efernie/express-subdomain-example) might be help you to set up subdomain in your express application.

**EDIT:**

Just put `target="_self"` on your link.

Example: `<a href="/link/to/file" target="_self">link</a>`

Source: [Conditionally have anchor links send user to a different page, rather than load to ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023338/conditionally-have-anchor-links-send-user-to-a-different-page-rather-than-load)

Comment: Thank you, I might try that for the sake of testing but ultimately right now this seems to be sophisticated for my need to only serve a couple of files...